# Existing ER Public Peering

Tags: peering, public

We've got currently 2 Express Route Circuits ( 2 VCs on each ) with Public peering.
Now, we have to provision the Express Route Circuits with same Service Keys due to some internal change and requirement from Network Dept.  Will we able to get the ER circuits re-provisioned and keep the public peering or we need to use the MS peering without fearing that peering won't work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General recommendation is to move to Microsoft Peering as it provides more control and flexibility. Public peering is also now deprecated.

My suggestion would be to take this change as an opportunity to migrate.  There is a nice article around transitioning here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/how-to-move-peering